# My prefix is a place with rounds

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> My prefix is a place with rounds,
>
> my infix begins like it sounds.
>
> My suffix is a line without repetition,
>
> overall, I transform with my emissions.

**What am I?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you a

> BARBECUE?

*My prefix is a place with rounds,*

> Serving rounds at the BAR.

*my infix begins like it sounds.*

> BE is a homophone of its initial letter B.

*My suffix is a line without repetition,*

> A QUEUE is a line, and without repetition of letters this becomes QUE/CUE.

*overall, I transform with my emissions.*

> The smoke from a barbecue can make a place smell different.